# Как красивее это написать?

Tags: c#

Есть метод `ReturnJson`, который возвращает config.
Затем я этот config использую в методе `GetInformation`. Все работает, но выглядит как-то некрасиво

```
public class ImdbService
{
     private static JsonConfig config = new JsonConfig();

     public async static Task GetInformation()
     {
        await ReturnJson();
        Console.WriteLine(config.ApiKey);
     }

     private async static Task<JsonConfig> ReturnJson()
     {
         var json = string.Empty;
         using (var fs = File.OpenRead("apikey.json"))
         using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
            json = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

         config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonConfig>(json);
         return config;
    }
}
```

В частности, мне не нравится использование `private static JsonConfig config = new JsonConfig();` и `await ReturnJson();`

Comment: 1. Убрать `static`. 2. Тут асинхронность бесмысленна, ибо я на 100% уверен, что в `apikey.json` у вас всего одна строка, а значит, достаточно простого `File.ReadAllText(...);`. 3. Вы уверены, что класс `ImdbService` должен отвечать за загрузку настроек приложения? Приведенный код должен наверно быть в `JsonConfig`? Ну и в 4. Может стоит использовать уже готовые решения? Сам .NET предлагает ряд своих, а из сторонних могу посоветовать [Config.Net](https://github.com/aloneguid/config).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, вы правы, так и сделаю. О готовых решениях не слышал, спасибо

Comment: Набросал небольшой [пример](https://pastebin.com/QKtTdUm3), как видите, ваш код можно очень сильно упростить и написать всего в пару строчек! И да, помните про простые правила "чем проще, тем лучше", ну и SRP из SOLID, не пихайте все в одну кучу, разбивайте на куски!

Comment: я использовал библиотеку, которую вы посоветовали, получилось вот так - <https://pastebin.com/6PHiE2HB>

Comment: Для .NET Core `private JsonConfig config = JsonSerializer.Deserealize<JsonConfig>(File.ReadAllText("apikey.json"));` - вообще без сторонних пакетов.